# jquery mobile slide out dialog box has previous leftover in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a simple jquery mobile slide out dialog box, the first time slide out works fine, a comment box shows up, where user can enter comments, then submit, then a "THANK YOU" will follow.

But when the user closes the dialog box and slide out the dialog box the second time, the "THANK YOU" still there, I want a fresh comment box generated instead.

Even when user enter something in the comment box without Submit, and just go back, the next slide out dialog box still shows the previously entered text!

Any help will be much appreciated.

This is the html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">

     <div data-role="header">
       <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
     </div>

     <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
       <p>Click on the link to see the slide effect.</p>
       <a href="#pagetwo" data-transition="slide">Slide to Dialog Page</a>
     </div>

     <div data-role="footer">
       <h1>Footer Text</h1>
     </div>

   </div>

   <div data-role="page" data-dialog="true" id="pagetwo">

     <div data-role="header">
       <h1>Thank You!</h1>
     </div>

     <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
       <form action="thankyou.asp" autocomplete="on">
         Comment:<input type="text" name="comment"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
       </form>
       <a href="#pageone">Go Back</a>
     </div>

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you never leave the page you have to reset the form manually using:

$("#form")[0].reset();

Comment: I want to do it automatically, behind the scene.